# Convert tif to other format in react js(jpeg/png)

Tags: reactjs

we are getting base64 encoded values of images from API(Backend service), when we tried one way to show those images and we successfully displayed in all browsers  when its jpeg type images. But tiff images are only support by safari, to show the tiff images in all browsers we need to find a way.

is there is a possibility of converting that tiff to other image format in react.